# GlassFish on Azure Windows VM - Connection failure

Tags: java, azure, glassfish, jms-topic

I have a GlassFish 4.0 web server installed on Azure Windows VM, which is to be used as a JMS message broker.

On GlassFish I have 2 resources:
Connection Factory : GFConnectionFactory, of type javax.jms.TopicConnectionFactory
Destination: myTopic, of type javax.jms.Topic

On the Network Security Group for my VM I have the following inbound rules: [NSG inbound rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8k0B.jpg)

When I start my VM + Glassfish and try to lookup the topic I get the following error:

```
org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: FINE: 00410001: Connection failure: socketType: IIOP_CLEAR_TEXT; hostname: localhost; port: 3700  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 1  completed: No
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.connectFailure(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:253)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ContactInfoImpl.createConnection(ContactInfoImpl.java:129)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ClientRequestDispatcherImpl.beginRequest(ClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:243)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ClientDelegateImpl.request(ClientDelegateImpl.java:227)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ClientDelegateImpl.is_a(ClientDelegateImpl.java:392)
    at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._is_a(ObjectImpl.java:130)
    at org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextHelper.narrow(NamingContextHelper.java:69)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext$ProviderCacheKey.getNameService(SerialContext.java:1205)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getRemoteProvider(SerialContext.java:393)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProvider(SerialContext.java:329)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:477)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at gla.prisoft.monitor.PSatMonitor.main(PSatMonitor.java:45)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:344)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:250)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:454)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:446)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.misc.ORBUtility.openSocketChannel(ORBUtility.java:110)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:329)
... 15 more
```

Here is the code as well:

```
public static Context getInitialContext() throws NamingException{
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
        properties.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
        //properties.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "iiop://localhost:3700");
        //properties.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "iiop://13.90.159.219:3700");
        properties.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "13.90.159.219:3700");
//      properties.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "13.90.159.219");
//      properties.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
        return new InitialContext(properties);
    }
public static void main(String []args ) throws NamingException{
        String topicname = "myTopic";
        Context initialContext = getInitialContext();
        topic = (Topic)initialContext.lookup(topicname);
        jmsContext = ((ConnectionFactory)initialContext.lookup("GFConnectionFactory")).createContext();
```

I don't understand why is it still trying to connect to localhost instead of the IP that I have specified.

Is it the VM configuration that is the problem (I've tried opening all ports and also turning off the firewall etc.) I can successfully connect from a browser on my local machine through http://13.90.159.219:3700 and also with "telnet 13.90.159.219 3700" from cmd.

I have also tried specifying the topic as "corbaname:iiop:host:port#a/b/name".

Any help o ideas will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just per my experience, I think some posts required for GlassFish were not be allowed in NSG, as you said, if opening all ports and turning off the firewall (I think the firewall you said is on Windows), then the connection works.

My suggestion is that you can try to use command `jps` & `netstat` on Azure VM as below to discover all ports used in GlassFish, then to allow these ports for inbound connection in NSG & Windows Firewall.

1. Using command `jps` on CMD to list all Java process id as `LIST 1`.
2. Using command `netstat -apn` to list all ports & `PID` of `LISTEN` as `LIST 2`.

Then, find out these `PID` which be listed in both of `LIST 1` & `LIST 2` and  to allow them in NSG & Windows firewall.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, unfortunately it didn't help :( must be something from glassfish